# How to sort a column which contains Coldfusion server-side generated values other than database values in jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server-2008, datatable, coldfusion

I am using  Datatables.net  for one of my page to display data.I am using server-side scripting to display datatables.

In my html I have 17 columns.Some columns for fetched values and other 3 contains some mathematics calculations with Coldusion functions that I am returning in the server side script.Those are not depending on database fields.

What my problem is I need to sort columns that have generated values.But this is not possible because datatables SQL ordering statement returns an error because these columns are not in the actual SQL table.

Doese anyone knows how can I sort these generated columns? Do we have any sorting that I can do for those columns without interfering SQL ordering clause(maybe sort in client side).

Comment: Alias the generated columns using `AS` and refer to them using the `columnDefs.name` in DataTables.net. You might want to provide some code to show how your current approach looks like.

Comment: @Alex But those columns are not in the database, so how can I use alias on columns that are not in the DB? those columns are generated in the cfloop.

Comment: Then you need to switch to DataTables's "ajax" variant, where you provide all the data serverside and let the client JS sort the data.

Comment: A google search on `sorting js datatable`  leads to this https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: @DanBracuk Thank you, but this is not what I need, this works only on client side not on serverside. as the data is processed by the server and displayed in the table in the form that is processed. So, when you want to sort a column a new call is sent  to the server and the server returns that data..On clientSide the data is manipulated in the DOM.

Comment: You can add the calculated data as hidden columns using `bVisible: false` and can sort accordingly.

Comment: Sorting is sorting.  If you can do it on the client, why bother with the server?

Comment: Not  necessarily. With pagination sorting must be handled server side, as the client doesn't receive the complete data set. Though it doesn't sound like that's the case here, server vs client sorting isn't always apples to apples.

Comment: Unless there's a good reason you must sort on the server side (like pagination) try sorting on the client side like @Beginner suggested.

Comment: @Ageax I need to query a table of 1 million records, so I need to create a pagination to return 100 results with every draw.

Comment: As pagination is involved so, it would be better to sort on the server side. @user1673306 It would be helpful if you could add the query in your question.

Comment: @user1673306 - Okay, you might want to add that to the question as it explains why server side sorting is a requirement.  Could we see the query in question - and calculation code - as well? Seeing it would help us determine if sorting *within* the db query is possible (it may not be). If it's not, then a QoQ as suggested below is probably the next option.

Comment: My answer was deleted because of new information - app has to sort 1,000,000 records.  A Q of Q on that would probably crash the server.

Comment: To be clear, I am assuming the database query only returns a PAGE of records at most (29, 50, 100, ...) **not all 1 million** - because that would be ... silly ;-)

Comment: @DanBracuk I've tried this method and this I encounter 2 issues : 1 the Q o Q is taking too much time and crash the page, 2 : if I limit the loop with startrow and endrow the columns where I have the calculations don't return the calculations when I do the draw for sorting. The first draw returns the correct info , when I try to sort desc or asc some of the rows are correct but some are not.

Comment: @Ageax 

 Yes, I limit the output to 100..I do this in the cfloop with startrow and endrow. I have tried to do this directly in the query with  something like this

  `WITH Rows AS
   (
    SELECT  
     column1,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY #sort#  #order# ) as [Row] 
      FROM table
        )
       SELECT 
          *
      FROM
        Rows 
        where Row >= #offset + 1# and Row <= #offset + limit#

but this returns only 100 results and datatable doesn't generate other pages.

Comment: @user1673306 - Run 2 queries. One to Count(*) the total records available. Another to get the page of records only. Then pass the total number of records and the data back to datatables. See https://datatables.net/manual/server-side for the parameters.

Comment: ...  look for the `recordsTotal` parameter section. That'll tell datatables it needs to display options for "..more pages".